# PHP Best Practices: Should a given parameter always have a consistent type?

Tags: php, types, parameters

I have a function that accepts a `checkGlossary` bool param as well as an optional `glossary` array.
Their states are directly tied together.
The glossary is *never* required if the bool is FALSE, and inversely, it is *always* required if the bool is TRUE.

To me, it seems like this could easily be simplified from:

```
// Current
function doSomething($param1, $param2, $checkGlossary=FALSE, $glossary=NULL){
    // blah blah blah
    if($checkGlossary)
        array_search($glossary[$param2]);
    // etc etc etc
}
```

... to:

```
// Proposed
function doSomething($param1, $param2, $glossary=FALSE){
    // blah blah blah
    if($glossary)
        array_search($glossary[$param2]);
    // etc etc etc
}
```

My only hesitation is over the fact that the type for `$glossary` (*bool* or *array*) would be unpredictable.
It doesn't bother me as long as I'm not going against some *Best-Practices* guidelines.

Thoughts?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to just drop the `checkGlossary` flag and use only the `glossary` variable. Set `array()` as default value and ommit the check if the array is empty.

Comment: Best practices: When a method takes more than 2 arguments, time to rethink (generally). </IMO>

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig Yours is my favorite answer to the question asked (because of specifying `array()` as the default value). If you put that in an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Hmmm ... looks like I've got some refactoring to look into :)     Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @mOrloff Okay. Posted it. Didn't have the time yesterday. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a bad idea to have function parameters with what PHP calls `mixed` datatype. It requires additional code in the function to check the type of the parameter and obviously it can get very confusing.

Probably the easiest solution in your special case would be to use the array length as indicator of whether to use the glossary code. You need a way to declare that the glossary array should not be used. So you should ask yourself: When is it pointless to use the glossary? When it's empty of course. So, I would suggest that you get rid of the flag and define `array()` as default for your other parameter:

```
function doSomething($param1, $param2, $glossary=array()) {
    if (count($array) > 0) {
        // do your glossary code here
    }
    // all the other stuff goes here
}
```

To me this seems semantically correct and works just fine.

I don't know what exactly you are building there, but another solution would be to put it all into a class and have the glossary as instance variable. In case you could use the glossary in several function calls. It would roughly look like this:

```
 public class SomeAccurateClassName {
     private $glossary = array();

     function setGlossary(array $glossary) {
         $this->glossary = $glossary;
     }

     function doSomething($param1, $param2) {
         if (count($array) > 0) {
             // do your glossary code here
         }
         // all the other stuff goes here
     }
 }
```

Considering that you basically have a state (use glossary or don't use glossary) it might be a good idea to encapsulate that withint a class.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the comprehensive answer/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`is_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) and [`is_bool()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php) to check its type!